# Verb ending in いでし

Tags: verbs, conjugations, archaic-language

In *Gosick* episode 19, a character says this line:

> ああ罪なる者よ‌汚れし血の泉より生まれ**いでし**お前に嘆きの祝福を

which is translated "Oh, sinner. To you, born from a spring of foul blood. I offer lamentable blessings".

I tried googling and looking around in my grammars to understand that 生まれいでし, but I wasn't able to find anything, and I'm not even sure if it's いでし, でし (with the い being part of a continuous form), or what else.

Since the sentence is said while the mother is giving birth, I'm guessing it's some form of (archaic?) continuous form, but even if that's correct I can't understand if there is any specific additional meaning with respect to a normal 生まれている form, beside an archaic undertone.

Comment: [いで](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%87%BA%E3%81%A5/) + [し](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%8D/#jn-50189)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

生まれいでし = 連体形 of the past 生れいでき of the present 生まれいづ, or 生れ出｛で｝る in modern language

Comment: Is 生まれいづる some particular archaic form, or just a verb? I looked in some dictionary, but I was unable to find it.

Comment: @Mauro いづる is 出る

Comment: It's 出【い】づ not 出【い】づる, いづる is the 連体形. It's a ダ行下二段 verb.

Comment: How does that conjugation work? a -づる verbs become -でし in past 連体形 form (-でした if not 連体形?)?

Comment: @Mauro As I've said, It is 出【い】づ and it belongs to the だ column, It's a 下二段 verb so Its conjugation is （で・で・づ・づる・づれ・でよ） This verb is the old form of 出る, in Japanese you add helper verbs to the conjugated verb to change the meaning. In classical Japanese, the helper verb for the past is き and it connects to the 連用形 of verbs so it becomes 出【い】でき, then the 連体形 of き is し so it becomes 出【い】でし. In modern Japanese た holds the same meaning as a couple of older helper verbs including き. So it would become 出【い】でた but it makes no sense to connect modern and old forms together.

Comment: 出【い】づる is the present (or whatever the default tense is called) 連体形 so it would modify the noun that comes after it, to make the verb itself be in the past you have to connect き but that doesn't connect to the 連体形 of the verb but to the 連用形 which is 出【い】で to become 出【い】でき. き doesn't always connect to the 連用形 though, it has different rules with irregular verbs.

Comment: I will also note that loss of initial *i-* in verb *ide-* → *de-* is very rare and irregular change, but it also happened in e.g.: *mudak-* → *udak-* → *idak-* → *dak-* ([抱く](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/抱く)), *imada* → *mada* ([未だ](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/未だ)).